# router.navigate doesn't redirect no error either

Tags: angular

I have this code:

```
        console.log('aa');
        let loc = '/' + this.config.AppTree.PApp.STModule.List.Path.toString();
        console.log('loc = ' + loc);
        this.router.navigate([loc], { state: { data: { abc: 1 } } });
        console.log('done, why no move?');
```

I added the console log, to see everything is all right, and I can see all 3 logs displayed, the screen never gets redirected.

loc variable is displayed correctly, just how it should look like

I tried to change some code around, and for example if I use `this.config.AppTree.DApp.OtherModule.List.Path` instead of `this.config.AppTree.PApp.STModule.List.Path`, then it works.

But to make it more confusing, some PApp paths work, some don't, and some DApp paths work, some don't.

I tried to add try catch, nothing happens.

Browser does not display any info, any error, and I find it odd that I get displayed the console log, and the redirect between them is handles like if it was a comment

PApp and DApp have 50+ module each inside, and redirecting with router.navigate usually works fine.

As I am new to Angular, what can I try? How can I make it display any warning or error, anything that will help me figure out why is the no navigation? Thanks

ng version info:

Angular CLI: 12.2.11
Node 16.13.0
Package manager: npm. 8.1.0
OS: win32 x64

Server side is .net Core